# como itero con un foreach php un arreglo de una consulta recibido mediante un post

Tags: php, bucle-for, post, foreach

tengo un blucle for que recibe un $row = $_POST['row'] y me realizo el siguiente recorrido:

```
      <td><?php echo  $suc?></td>
      <td><?php echo $_POST['Fecha']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $_POST['Hora'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $_POST['tipo'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $_POST['caja'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $_POST['cajafactura'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $_POST['cajeta_nombre'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $_POST['cod_SAP'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $_POST['barra'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $_POST['descri_mater'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $_POST['Prec_Unit'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $_POST['IVA'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $_POST['Uni_Vendidas'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $_POST['Uni_devueltas'] ?></td>
  </tr>
```

el hace el recorrido de los registros pero me vuisualiza la repeticion de un mismo registro por la cantidad de registros encontrados, como si estuviera dulpicado los registros,pero no lo estan solo que si encuentra 4 registros de la consulta toma unos de ellos y los repite 4 vecez

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ $q=$q+1;?>
">

```
       <input type="hidden" name="Fecha" value="<?php echo $row['Fecha']; ?>">
       
       
       <input type="hidden" name="Hora" value="<?php echo $row['Hora']; ?>">
       
       
       <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="<?php echo $row['tipo']; ?>">
       
       
       <input type="hidden" name="caja" value="<?php echo $row['caja']; ?>">
       
       
       <input type="hidden" name="cajafactura" value="<?php echo $row['cajafactura']; ?>">
       
       
       <input type="hidden" name="cajeta_nombre" value="<?php echo $row['cajeta_nombre']; ?>">
```

">

```
       <input type="hidden" name="tienda" value="<?php echo $tienda ?>">
```

Comment: Por favor agrega todo el código que participa en la función... pero suena a problema de bucle while.

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($_POST);` y agrega el resultado a la pregunta, así como el código completo del bucle que refieres.

Comment: le agregue el var_dum($_POST) y ya vi que solo recibe un registro de la consulta por ejemplo de 2 registros, recibo uno y con el blucle for repite el mismo registro

Comment: Agrega el bucle completo por favor

Comment: Por favor, el código va como texto con formato código, no como imagen.